# Lost keystore password, what are my options?

Tags: java, certificate, keystore, keytool

I have a keystore that I used to generate some `.csr` files, sent these off and got back `.p7b` files. However I managed to lose my keystore password, I saw there is a brute force java program to work it out however I know my password is 15 characters long and this would take a very long time. I also tried creating a new keystore from the old one, like some people had suggested but it still requires me to enter the password and fails without it.

Am I likely to run into problems if I just create a new keystore and import the certificates into that one or do I have to request new certificates?

Comment: Test all combinations and wait a really long time (or maybe it gets it in the first try, you might be lucky) OR wait for quantum computing to improve which will render all current encryption methods useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I likely to run into problems if I just create a new keystore and import the certificates into that one

You will run into the problem that you can't do it. You've lost access to the private key.

> or do I have to request new certificates?

You have to create a new keystore, keypair, CSR, get it signed, import it, ...

Comment: That is what I thought, I was hoping there was some magic solution. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's a bit more complicated. In spite of its name, a Java 'keystore' can actually contain any combination of:

- PrivateKeyEntry -- contains privatekey *and* matching certificate or chain, used to prove your own identity, particularly for an SSL/TLS server
- TrustedCertEntry -- contains cert, usually root CA cert, used to verify *other* parties, including SSL/TLS client(s) verifying server(s)
- (only in some formats, not common JKS) SecretKeyEntry -- not relevant here

See [the javadoc for `java.security.KeyStore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html). In fact the 'truststore' of CA certs used by SSL/TLS (including HTTPS) clients in Java to verify servers is normally a keystore file, by default JRE/lib/security/cacerts which is supplied as part of the JRE (for Oracle-formerly-Sun packages) or linked from it (for OpenJDK, at least in systems I've used).

Thus if you tell `keytool` to import your own certificate(s) to a new keystore file, it will do so -- but as trusted cert entry(ies) that can identify someone else, not as a privatekey entry that can identify you. The only indication is a subtle one: `keytool` will say `Certificate was added` (which means a trustedcert) NOT `Certificate reply was installed` (which means a matching privatekey).

If you then use this cert-only-not-privatekey keystore for an SSL/TLS server, it will not give any immediate or obvious error; normally it will instead reject all connection attempts as 'no cipher suites in common'. (If both endpoints have configured to allow 'anonymous' ciphersuites the connection will/may succeed with an anonymous suite, but this gives no security against now-common active attacks and therefore is not usually done.)

But this doesn't change the result: without the passphrase and thus access to the old privatekey, you're wedged and must start over. Note that if you used a paid CA many (IME most) of them allow 'rekeying' a cert for the same domainname(s) free or at a substantial discount.